# How to share the same folder in EFS between deployments in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I have an EKS cluster with multiple deployments (microservices). I would like all of them to write logs to same folder in an EFS mount even between restarts/scaling etc. Currently it creates a folder with the persistent volume id, which breaks our requirement. Is it possible to always mount the same folder even when the persistent volume is recreated. Can it always to point to the same folder in EFS?

It currently creates folders like this:
"/logs/pvc-2exxxcxs4-0xx7-4e11-813a-65xxxxxxxx/"

Instead, I would like it to be just "/logs" or a fixed path without any dependency on pvc id/name.

Below are the current yamls:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
    ........
        volumeMounts:
        - name: dev-logs-efs
          mountPath: /logs
      volumes:
      - name: dev-logs-efs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: dev-logs-efs-pvc

---

kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: dev-logs-efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  provisioningMode: efs-ap
  fileSystemId: fs-xxxxxxxxxxx
  basePath: "/logs"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dev-logs-efs-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: dev-logs-efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Comment: For the sake of log organization, having separate folder for each microservice sounds like a great idea to me. This is also the typical setup as far as I know for most applications, such as `/var/logs/nginx`, `var/logs/squid`, etc. Why would you need all of it to be in the same folder? In fact, I can think it could be messy if, for example, different microservice accidentally have the same log name format. It will overwrite another service's logs!

Comment: Agree. Thats how it's done. But it's handled at individual microservice level. The above mounting is for the base folder for logs, individual microservice services will create specific folders similar to nginx, squid etc depending on their configured names. The problem is with the "pvc-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxx-xxxx" folder it creates each time the PVC is changed/recreated.  @RegisterSole

Comment: I see. Despite the `pvc...` folders being created, are you able to access the base `mountPath`, i.e., `logs/`? This [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-efs-csi-dynamic-provisioning/) seems to indicate you can. See the part where it does `cat example/out.txt`. `example/` is the `mountPath` in the article.

Comment: Im facing the same issue, did you ever find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The Storage Class Parameter **ensureUniqueDirectory** is what you are looking for; the official
[aws-efs-csi-driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/master/docs/README.md) documentation states:

> Used when dynamic provisioning is enabled, if set to true, appends the a UID to the pattern specified in subPathPattern to ensure that access points will not accidentally point at the same directory.

This value is set to **true** by default but in your case should be set to **false**.

Your EFS StorageClass could look like this:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  provisioningMode: efs-ap
  fileSystemId: fs-92107410
  directoryPerms: "700"
  gidRangeStart: "1000" # optional
  gidRangeEnd: "2000" # optional
  basePath: "/dynamic_provisioning" # optional
  subPathPattern: "${.PVC.namespace}/${.PVC.name}" # optional
  ensureUniqueDirectory: "false" # <-- set to false
  reuseAccessPoint: "false" # optional
```